# Conditional ZSH_THEME by terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to make that when .zshrc when invoked chooses a specific theme based on which terminal amulator i'm running. For this I came up with:

```
current_terminal="$(ps -p$PPID -o cmd=)"

function choose_theme {
        if [ $current_terminal=~'tilix' ];
        then echo 'powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k';
        else echo 'robbyrussell';
        fi
}

ZSH_THEME="$(choose_theme)"
```

I don't get any error message when running and when I open on tilix it works just fine with the powerlevel9k theme, but just that, it doesn't seem to respect the condition and I don't know where might my mstake be =/

The output for the variable current_terminal in each terminal emulator i'm using are:

Tilix:

```
/usr/bin/tilix --gapplication-service
```

Default Terminal:

```
/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

So it's getting things wright, but setting up always the first option for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work due to two reasons:

1. You are using `[ ... ]` instead of `[[ ... ]]` for the check. The difference is that `[[ ... ]]` is part of the ZSH's syntax and `[` (aka `test`) is a built-in command that tries to emulate the external `test` program. This matters because `[` does not support the `=~` operator, it is only available inside `[[ ... ]]`.
2. The `=~` (like any other operator) needs to be surrounded by white spaces. As a Unix shell ZSH tokenizes command on white spaces. In this case ZSH I would guess that ZSH only checks whether `$current_terminal=~'tilix'` evaluates to a non-empty string instead of comparing `$current_terminal` to `'tilix'`. This is always the case, hence why you always get the powerlevel9k theme.

So the condition should look like this:

```sh
current_terminal="$(ps -p$PPID -o cmd=)"

function choose_theme {
    if [[ $current_terminal =~ 'tilix' ]];
    then echo 'powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k';
    else echo 'robbyrussell';
    fi
}

ZSH_THEME="$(choose_theme)"
```